# rospy.loginfo is not printing when node is started with a launch file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did the very helpfull beginner tutorials and wanted to apply what I learned on a self written example. Therefore I wrote a package called "calculate" with a "calc_talker" node that calculates the fibonacci numbers and a "calc_listener" node that listens to them.

**calc_talker:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from calculate.msg import Calc

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher("Calc_Chatter", Calc, queue_size=100)
    rospy.init_node("Calc_Talker", anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)

    count   = 3
    number1 = 1
    number2 = 1

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():

        result = number1 + number2

        msg = Calc()
        msg.first_number = number1
        msg.second_number = number2
        msg.result = f"The {count} fibonacci number is {result}"

        number2 = number1
        number1 = result
        count = count + 1

        rospy.loginfo(msg)
        pub.publish(msg)
        rate.sleep()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
#EoF
```

**calc_listener:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from calculate.msg import Calc

def callback(data):
    msg = f"{data.result}. It was calculated from {data.first_number} and {data.second_number}"
    rospy.loginfo(msg)
    
    
def listener():
    rospy.init_node("Calc_Listener", anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("Calc_Chatter", Calc, callback)
      rospy.spin()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    listener()
#EoF
```

When i start the nodes with rosrun i get the following example output:

**rosrun calculate calc_talker.py:**

```
[INFO] [1612869970.095087]: first_number: 1 second_number 1 result: "The 3 fibonacci number is 2"
```

**rosrun calculate calc_listener.py:**

```
[INFO] [1612869970]: The 3 fibonacci number is 2. It was calculated from 1.0 and 1.0
```

I wrote a simple launch file to launch both nodes:

```
<launch>

    <group ns="talker">
        <node pkg="calculate" name="my_calc_talker" type="calc_talker.py"/>
    </group>

    <group ns="listener">
        <node pkg="calculate" name="my_calc_listener" type="calc_listener.py" output="screen"/>
    </group>

</launch>
```

**My Problem:**
When i add output="screen" to the calc_talker i get the expected log output. However i does not work when i add it to the calc_listener and i can not find out why. I am very grateful for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371399/rospy.loginfo-is-not-printing-when-node-is-started-with-a-launch-file/) by [mab0189](https://answers.ros.org/users/69650/mab0189/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2021-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey mab0189!

The reason that you cannot see the log info is because your callback `callc_listener.callback` is never executed.

But why is that? Well in this case it is from the grouping of each node under a different namespace.

Your `talker` node is under the `"talker"` namespace meaning that (unless specified to be global) subscriptions are nested under that namespace. This means that your talker node is publishing to the topic `/talker/Calc_Chatter` and similarly your listener is listening on the topic `/listener/Calc_Chatter`. These two topics are clearly different and that is the root of your issue.

The solution is therefore to remove the (in this case) unneeded `group` tags that currently wrap your nodes in the launch file.
try...

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="calculate" name="my_calc_talker" type="calc_talker.py" output="screen"/>
    <node pkg="calculate" name="my_calc_listener" type="calc_listener.py" output="screen"/>
</launch>
```

A few other notes.

1. You can check my analysis of the topics by running `rostopic list` after launching your launch file.
2. You are correct in that `output="screen"` is required for the logging to be visible when using the launch file.
3. Namespacing is a tricky topic (I struggle with it still). you can read more on it [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Names).

---

Originally posted by [robodan](https://answers.ros.org/users/69695/robodan/) with karma: 26 on 2021-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mab0189](https://answers.ros.org/users/69650/mab0189/) on 2021-02-10**:
@robodan thank you very much for this comprehensive answer! As you suggested i checked your analysis with rostopic list and you are correct. I also used the rqt_graph tool to visualise it. I should have done it in the first place but since it worked with rosrun i thought the bug must lie elsewhere.